# Why Integrate gives warning "Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50. reached" when working on purely symbolic expression?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic, warning-messages

Report to WRI   **[CASE:4959987]**

---

in V 13.1, integrating a symbolic expression gives an `N::meprec` message:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*The question is* why would this be generated since everything is symbolic?

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"PrintAction"}] = {"PrintToNotebook"}
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"MessageOptions", 
   "KernelMessageAction"}] = {"PrintToNotebook", "Beep"}

integrand = ((Log[2]^2 + ((-2)*x^3 + 2*x^2 + (-6)*x)*
  Log[2] + (x^6 + (-2)*x^5 + 7*x^4 + (-6)*x^3 + 9*x^2))*
  Exp[x + 2] + ((-1)*Log[2] + ((-2)*x^3 + x^2)))/(Log[2]^2 + ((-2)*x^3 + 2*x^2 + (-6)*x)*Log[2] + (x^6 + (-2)*x^5 + 7*x^4 + (-6)*x^3 + 9*x^2));

Integrate[integrand, x]
```

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

V 13.1 on windows 10

ps. This integral was obtained from Fricas integration test suite.

pps. I do not know/remember now if this was asked here before or not.

Comment: On version 12.1 I get no errors and the result after `FullSimplify` is $e^{x+2}+\frac{1}{(x-1) x-\frac{\log (2)}{x}+3}$.  Strange error you're getting considering `2Log@2-Log@4==0`.

Comment: According to the stack trace in the error message, it is from `Sign[2 Log[2] - Log[4]]`, which also gives the error if evaluated separately. (V13.1, Mac M1) -- Presumably, Mma is trying to prove numerically that the sign is +1 or -1. Perhaps there is a missing `Quiet[]` internally.

Comment: I think it should be tagged [tag:bugs].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the stack trace in the `N::meprec` error message, it is from `Sign[2 Log[2] - Log[4]]`, which is called when `ComplexInfinity (2 Log[2] - Log[4])` is evaluated. Both also give the error if evaluated separately.  The `ComplexInfinity (2 Log[2] - Log[4])`, which evaluates to `ComplexInfinity` and should be `Indeterminate`, suggests to me that `Integrate` might be making the wrong conclusion at this point. Consequently, it suggests the following workaround and that this is a bug that should be reported.

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Log},
 Unprotect[Log];
 Log[4] = 2 Log[2];
 Protect[Log];
 Integrate[integrand, x]]

(*  E^(2 + x) + x/(3 x - x^2 + x^3 - Log[2])  *)
```

*Update*

The following is a simpler workaround, but the one above more strongly suggests to me that `Integrate` is probably making an avoidable mistake.

```
Integrate[integrand /. Log[2] -> Log[4]/2, x]
```

Comment: Well, it sees it is zero after FullSimplify...

Comment: Still a problem in 13.2.0. Also, it still works with FullSimplify[Sign[2 Log[2] - Log[4]]] or with Sign[FullSimplify[2 Log[2] - Log[4]]]

Comment: This solves now, BTW. But it is a super big antiderivative with rootof objects.